# How to redirect magento's site from http to https in magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, https

My question is about how to redirect magento's site from http to https in magento 1.9?

Comment: Have  you configured Secure URl in admin end?

Comment: Yes. (System > Configuration > General > Web). Set yes in "use secure url in frontend".

Comment: have you purchase SSL certificate you site?

Comment: can you please share you site url

Comment: System > Config > General > Web. Just add the HTTPs in front of the URL and make sure to check use secure URLs in the frontend.

for eg.https://example.com/

Comment: Yes..I added https in front of the URL..It gives file not found error..